# Saving Canvas Background along with Canvas contents

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, background

I would think this is a common problem, but I can't seem to find a simple solution to it. I have a canvas (I am actually using sketch.js but I don't think that matters) with a background image, for example a Storm Trooper:

[image]

I then thru Sketch.js allow the user to write scribble on it:
[image]

When getting the image from the canvas I only get it canvas image:

[image]

What I really want it both (just like it looks on the screen, 2nd capture above).

I have tried merging the background image back in without success. Ultimately this result is pushed to S3 - so I am not looking for a way to push it into another HTML element, I would prefer a grabbing of the canvas and background together. But if not possible, I would imagine some sort of merge must take place.

HTML:

```
        <div id="annotationmodal" class="modal">
        <div class="annotation-container" id="annotation_{{id}}">
            <div class="tools" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <canvas id="tools_sketch_inlinephoto" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" style="background: url(@Url.Content("~")my/stuff/amazon/{{value}}/redirect) no-repeat center center;"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-solid-grey btn-sm" onclick="device.annotationCancel();" value="Cancel" style="margin-right: 15px;" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-solid-green btn-sm" onclick="device.annotationSave(this, '{{id}}');" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   annotationSave: function (element, id) {
        var fileExtension = "jpg";
        var canvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch_inlinephoto");
        var data = canvas.toDataURL();
        var key = device.uploadDataUri(fileExtension, "image/" + fileExtension, data);
        $("#annotationmodal").detach();
        if (settings.focusedField) {
            settings.focusedField.focus();
        }
    }
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Note that the background image is being pulled from S3 also...

Comment: I've done something similar before using Literally Canvas. You may have ran into the same problem I had. There may be two canvases. One has the image and one has your drawing. If you draw them on top of each other, it will merge them.  example: `var snapshot = document.getElementById('snapshot');
var context = snapshot.getContext('2d');

// Flatten the canvas background and effects
context.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0], 0, 0, 640, 480);
context.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[1], 0, 0, 640, 480);`

Comment: @Wes 4 Thanks. So in this example is the [0] the background and the [1] the portion of the canvas that the user is writing to? And if done in this manner will the canvas.toDataURL() return them merged?

Comment: The text was kind of messy with the comment so I put it in the answer below. That's correct. I used `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before using Literally Canvas. You may have ran into the same problem I had. There may be two canvases. One has the image and one has your drawing. I wasn't sure what Literally Canvas used for their canvas name so I selected the first and second canvas element with Javascript using `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]‌`

If you use drawImage, you can stack them on top of each other, it will merge them. 640x480 is the dimensions of the image I had. You should change that part to match yours.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch_inlinephoto");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

// Flatten the canvas background and effects 
context.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]‌​, 0, 0, 640, 480); 
context.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[1]‌​, 0, 0, 640, 480);

var savedImage = new Image();
savedImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: The javascript seems to be seriously unhappy with the context.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]‌​, 0, 0, 640, 480); 
context.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[1]‌​, 0, 0, 640, 480); Any ideas of why?

Comment: Did you change the dimensions 640x480 at the end to match yours?

Comment: Yes. It the two lines above - they do not even compile. Here is what I have:               var canvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch_inlinephoto");
            var cnxt = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
 
            // Flatten the canvas background and effects 
            cnxt.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]‌​, 0, 0, 500, 700); 
            cnxt.drawImage(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[1]‌​, 0, 0, 500, 700);  Won't even run in browser - crashes.Too strange

Answer (score 0):

Use html2canvas library to save canvas background along 
with canvas content

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
html2canvas (c, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var blob = canvas.toDataURL();
        var pika = document.createElement("a");
        pika.href = blob;
        var d = new Date();
        pika.download = d+".png";
        pika.click();
    }
})
```

The above code downloads your canvas background with canvas content as a png image. Don't forget to include the library `<script src="html2canvas.js"> </script>`